# New search method in API

Tags: box-api

I want to understand how to use new method https://developers.box.com/docs/#search for fectch all folders? Could you please give me any example how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search isn't really meant for fetching all folders in an account.  It's meant for finding all folders with the name "Jurassic Park," or folders that contain documents referring to "monsters."

You can specify folders to look in, or file-extensions you care about, or that you only want to get type=folder,  but you have to include some kind of query string.

Full docs [here](https://developers.box.com/docs/#search)